# nl2br() creates an extra new line when Edit Option used

Tags: php, mysql, nl2br

I am using textarea to save content in mySQL DB and using `nl2br` to preserve line breaks used by user.

PHP method of using `nl2br`

```
$description = safe_var($_POST['description']);
$text = preg_replace('#[\r\n]+#', "\n", $description);
$description_html = nl2br($text);
```

Now, when i am using edit option of update the `description` then there is a new `<br/>` added everytime i press update button.

It means that if first time my content looks like as below

```
Line 1
-----one space
Line 2
----- One space
Line 3
```

And then if i update this content with some words then i get output like as below and this is not expected

```
Line 1
-----one space
-----one space
Line 2
----- One space
-----one space
Line 3
-----one space
Line 4
```

Is there any way to prevent new lines to already added spaces until unless user gives a space.

Comment: Make sure that textarea tag is in one line.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should only escape userdata when inserting it in a database. If you format your data when displaying it to a user, you would not have this problem.

You insert it in your database with the newlines, you display it with nl2br, that way, when you edit your file, no newlines wil appear.